# What are the security risks of giving everyone read permission on this setup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions

We have a folder named `distributors`. And under that folder, there are subfolders that serves as home directories of ftp users.

Example:

`distributors/a` w/c serves as the home directory of ftp user `a`

`distributors/b` w/c serves as the home directory of ftp user `b`

Those ftp users are the ftp accounts of our distributors and they are uploading their inventory (a csv file) to their home directories.

Our cron job w/c is a rake task needs to be able to read the csv files. When the ftp users uploads a file, the owner and group of the file by default is the name of the ftp user. To let our cron job be able to read the files, we are planning to set the default permission of the files being uploaded to `a+r` w/c will let everyone be able to read the file.

Now the question is, what are the security risks on allowing everyone to be able to read the file?

I'm assuming ftp user `a` won't be able to go to the folder of user `b` since ftp user `a` can't go out on user's a home directory w/c is `distributors/a`

Comment: Security risk in everyone reading the file that depends upon your system what secured information you expose?. If you don't want to user to access then you can stop providing read access also. You can provide rw only to privilege ones.

Comment: Maybe it could be more on topic on [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com). Anyway, you should at least say whether user a should be able to read the files from user b or not, and who should be allowed the read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple choice here. About Security risk, if the files content are sensitive I would recommend to not give other read permission to them, because every user will able to read them who have user on the host.

You could add the the user run the corn job into the group of the ftp users. 
But it will give that user extra privileges to read or probably modify ftp related files. Better to give other read permission as you mentioned,

However I would use ACL ( Access Control Lists ) for this, it a little harder to manage but give more freedom to make strict security. You could make every file you like to be readable for the user run corn job without change the current permissions.

```
setfacl -Rm "u:user:r" ./dirNfile # add user read permission to directory tree
setfacl -dRm "u:user:r" ./dirNfile # Make default for the further created files on all sub directory R stand for recursive
getfacl ./dirNfile # Check acl config on a file
setfacl -x "u:user" ./fileNdir # remove entry 
setfacl -b ./fileNdir # remove all ACL entry from a file or dir
```

Directory or file have acl entry will be showed by ls command at the end of the permission with a + mark `drwxr-x---+`

Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists for more info

Comment: "because every user will able to read them who have user on the host". I'm the only one who has a user account on the host aside from the distributors because they have an ftp account. But I thought they won't be able to access anything that is outside their home directory? Like in the context of my example above, user A won't be able to access the home directory of user B?

Comment: There is many way to define ftp user. Depend on the ftp server configuration. I familiar with vsftpd configuration, I could go into details if you use it as well. 

 I recommend to make a test user like a and b user and test if you able to leave the home dir unless you have a and b password as well then you could test the actual users.

Comment: Yes we're using vsftpd. The ftp user can't leave their home directory, we followed this tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vsftp-chroot-users-limit-to-only-their-home-directory.html

Comment: Since you are tested I suppose ftp users created way they not able to leave their home directory, and you are the only user who able to access the host, I see no issue to proceed with other read permission add, but still there is could be risk, there is a way brake into the server trough poorly configured services and get access to file system with the user the service use, that is why we avoid to run services with root user, trough http for example. Since you only planing provide read access I don't see issue here if the data is not sensitive.

Comment: Alright. Thank you.